# AMP pages for multi lingual website hosted on subdomain

Tags: seo, amp

I have a multilingual website hosted on 10 multiple subdomains.e.g

```
hindi.example.com 
english.example.com 
korean.example.com 
...
```

Here each subdomain is a different search property in Google search console.

Google recommends to have amp page urls either in subdomain or in a directory. My code is written in a way that my amp pages are written using a different tech stack and hosted on a different server. So my approach was to implement amp page urls in following way -

```
amp.example.com/english/ 
amp.example.com/hindi/ 
....
```

Is this fine from amp and seo perspective ? Or I need to follow a different approach like -

```
amp.english.example.com/ 
amp.hindi.example.com/
```

Please help me understand which approach is recommended from Google AMP and SEO perspective.

From tech stack limitation I cannot use following -

```
hindi.example.com/amp/  
engish.example.com/amp/ 
....
```